# Subtract last year sales from this year sales of each client with mysql (more entries a year [sum first])

Tags: mysql

Like already written in the title I would firstly sum all sales of each client for **last year** and **this year** and then subtract last year from this year `(last year - this year)` for each client.

**Edit:**

```
   clientid | ....date..... | quant    | product. | client | place    | price | 
 ......1... |2016-01-10     | ...1.... | product1 | anna   | Italy... | .100. | 
 ......1... |2016-04-12     | ...2.... | product2 | anna   | Italy... | .300. | 
 ......1... |2017-01-10     | ...1.... | product1 | anna   | Italy... | .200. | 
 ......1... |2017-04-12     | ...2.... | product1 | anna   | Italy... | .400. |
```

So the result of anna in the last year should be 400 and this year 600. diff should be 200.

I already tried some query but it's too complicated for me:

```
SELECT 
    `date`, `quant`, `clientid`,  `product`, `client`, `place`, lastyear.price, thisyear.price , (lastyear.price - thisyear.price) AS diff
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        `date`, `quant`, `product`, `client`, `place`, SUM(price)
    FROM
        `verkauf`
    WHERE
        `date` BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 24 MONTH AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-31') - INTERVAL 12 MONTH ) 

        )as lastyear,

    (SELECT 
        `date`, `quant`, `product`, `client`, `place`, SUM(price)
    FROM
        `verkauf`
    WHERE
        `date` BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-31')

        )as thisyear
WHERE 
    `clientid` = :id 
ORDER BY 
    diff ASC  
LIMIT 
    :start, :limit
```

Comment: share table with some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this. In one subquery I am taking sum of current year and in another subquery taking the sum of previous year and using both to get the different.

```
Select
   m1.clientid,
   m1.cyear,
   m0.pyear,
   m1.sum csum,
   m0.sum psum,
   (
      m1.sum - m0.sum
   )
   diff 
from
   (
      select
         clientid,
         cyear,
         sum 
      from
         (
            select
               clientid,
               year(date) cyear,
               sum(price) sum 
            from
               buget 
            group by
               clientid,
               cyear
         )
         T 
      where
         cyear = year(curdate())
   )
   m1,
   (
(
      select
         clientid, pyear, sum 
      from
         (
            select
               clientid,
               year(date) pyear,
               sum(price) sum 
            from
               buget 
            group by
               clientid,
               pyear
         )
         T 
      where
         pyear = 
         (
            year(curdate())
         )
          - 1) m0
   )
where
   m1.clientid = m0.clientid
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8560fa/5 i did something wrong ? @Suhail AKhtar

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle and sorry about that I have updated the query plz try this.

`Select m1.clientid, m1.cyear,m0.pyear,m1.sum csum,m0.sum psum, (m1.sum-m0.sum) diff from (select clientid, cyear,sum from (select clientid, year(date) cyear, sum(price) sum from buget group by clientid,cyear) T where cyear=year(curdate())) m1 , ((select clientid, pyear,sum from (select clientid, year(date) pyear, sum(price) sum from buget group by clientid,pyear) T where pyear=(year(curdate()))-1) m0) where m1.clientid = m0.clientid`

Comment: wow thank you so much it's working. Awesome ! You made my weekend thanks =).

Comment: Oh i explored a problem. How to "sum" all productnames ? Because for example Anna has more then 1 product but it shows always only the first: http://rextester.com/NRLGT65891

Comment: i would output like that: |Name|product past|product current|psum|csum|diff|  ----  |Anna|product1, product2|product 3, product4| 800| 500| 300|

Comment: oh i solved by myself ;D. http://rextester.com/XZB86079 GROUP_CONCAT(product SEPARATOR ' ')

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

```
select ABS(t3.price2 - t2.price1),t1.client from buget t1 inner join (select sum(price) as price1 from buget where year(date) = year(now()) group by client) t2 on year(date) = year(now()) inner join (select sum(price) as price2 from buget where year(date) = year(now()) - 1 group by client) t3 group by client;
```

Comment: Sorry guys im late, but this is only working if there is only 1 client ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60dc1e/1

Comment: @Jason use group by client.

Comment: thats very close i think, just the result isn't correct i get 500 for anna and 600 for Peter http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8560fa/6

Comment: it looks like it just sums the current year.

Comment: ahh i had to use group by in the inner too, but i get a error now:  Subquery returns more than 1 row  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60dc1e/9

Comment: Hmm, i get everytime the same result 200 for both wich is correct firstly, but if i change the values it stays 200.

Comment: ahh the site stopped working =). Propably to complicated =). I tried on another site and it looks like that it's working for the first client. Awesome !! The onliest problem is the second client always has the same value like the first. http://rextester.com/MKVNL43417